# Group focused their attention or attentions - are both grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

> The other group, comprised of Alice and Bob, focused their attentions on Charlie.

Is this grammatical? Or does it need to be changed to 'attention'?

My understanding is that Alice and Bob could each have their own separate attention, and so both attentions can be focused.

Or, would the subject be seen as 'the group', a singular entity with one attention?

(Or is my entire understanding wrong and even 'Alice and Bob focused their attentions on Charlie' would be incorrect?)

Comment: 'Attention' is never used as a count usage (to my knowledge) in this precise sense ('They concentrated on what Charlie was saying'). I'll let you check in say three dictionaries. So 'attentions' isn't correct here. 'They focused their attention on Charlie' must be seen as an idiom, an unexpected but commonly used expression, for after all we'd probably say 'they focused their minds on Charlie'.

Comment: 'Attention' is never used as a count usage (to my knowledge) in this precise sense ('They concentrated on what Charlie was saying'). I'll let you check in say three dictionaries; I'd suggest Macmillan. So 'attentions' isn't correct here. 'They focused their attention on Charlie' must be seen as an idiom, an unexpected but commonly used expression, for after all we'd probably say 'they focused their minds on Charlie'.